# react different to multiple async calls

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Imagine the following scenario :

```
public async Task DoMultipleWork() {
    var uploadTask = UploadAsync(file);
    var processingTask = Task.Run( () => DoCpuWork() );

    await Task.WhenAll(uploadTask, processingTask);
    Console.WriteLine("upload is done");
    Console.WirteLine("processing is done");
}
```

How can I change that code so that it doesn't matter which one ends first, it execute some particular (sync or async) code.

So I fire the both task and when `taskA` or `taskB` ends, I just run some code (sync or async) independently of the other.

I think maybe `ContinueWith` but I'm not sure because it needs an another async method which is not really needed.

**EDIT** 
As suggested by comments on answer, I want to clear that I want to execute different code depending on the task that completes, and get both Console.WriteLine executed as soon as the original task completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I describe on my blog, [`ContinueWith` is dangerous unless you explicitly pass a scheduler](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html). You should use `await` instead of `ContinueWith` in ~99% of cases (more detail in [another blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html)).

In your case:

```
private async Task UploadAsync(string filepath)
{
  var result = await fileManager.UploadAsync(filepath);
  Console.WriteLine($"Result from uploading file {result}");
}

private async Task ProcessAsync(string filepath, IProgress<T> progress)
{
  await Task.Run(() => wordProcessor.Process(filepath, progress));
  Console.WriteLine("processing completed");
}

...

await Task.WhenAll(UploadAsync(filepath), ProcessAsync(filepath, processingProgress));
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to use `Task.WhenAny` which returns the first task that completes. You can then tell which task completed by comparing to the original tasks. Before returning you should wait for the other one to complete explicitly (or wait for both with `Task.WhenAll`):

```
public async Task DoMultipleWork() 
{
    var uploadTask = UploadAsync(file);
    var processingTask = Task.Run( () => DoCpuWork() );

    var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(uploadTask, processingTask);
    Console.WriteLine("upload or processing is done");
    if (completedTask == uploadTask)
    {
        // Upload completed
    }
    else
    {
        // Processing completed
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(uploadTask, processingTask) // Make sure both complete
    Console.WriteLine("upload and processing are done");
}
```

Comment: I would use ContinueWith and the continuation task and then WhenAll.

Comment: @EliAlgranti ContinueWith on what?

Comment: @EliAlgranti I like the syntactic sugar of `ContinueWith` much better, but the code to execute doesn't has to be async and looks like `ContinueWith` requires to be async. isn't it ?

Comment: @Bart again, `ContinueWith` on what? You need a continuation that runs after either task....

Comment: Bart yes, the continue with would be another task and would not necessarily run in the same thread as the "main" task, but the "main" task gets dispatched to the task queue on the fourth line when await is first invoked so I don't think thread affinity is a problem here.

Comment: @i3arnon see Payman answer. Both are good answers but I will stick to the `ContinueWith` because that makes more sense in **my** current code and can't accept both :D

Comment: @Bart These answers address different questions. If you meant to have two different actions that each follows one of the tasks then you should probably edit your question to make that clear. If you meant having a single action that happens after either task completes then the other answer is wrong.

Comment: @i3arnon I cleared that up. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Bart That doesn't clear it up. Let's say you have a continuation `uploadCon` for `uploadTask` and `processCon` for `processingTask`. If `uploadTask` completed first, you want to run `uploadCon` but do you also want to run `processCon` or not?

Comment: @i3arnon yes, I want to run BOTH tasks. i'll edit again.

Comment: @i3arnon I don't want to do it after WhenAll because that will make it wait for both tasks. I want to fire the continuation as soon as the task completes. If taskA takes 1 minute and taskB takes 3 minutes, I want to execute conA as soon as taskA completes (so at 1 minute mark) and later when taskB completes, then fire conB (at 3 minute mark)

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task DoMultipleWork() {
var uploadTask = UploadAsync(file);
var processingTask = Task.Run( () => DoCpuWork() );

uploadTask.ContinueWith((Task t) => Console.WriteLine("YOUR_MESSAGE"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

processingTask.ContinueWith((Task t) => Console.WriteLine("YOUR_MESSAGE"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

await Task.WhenAll(new []{uploadTask, processingTask});

}
```

Comment: Why `TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion`?

Comment: nice, what's the NotOnRanToCompletion ??

Comment: you can use None as well depends on your needs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx but definitly no NotOnRanToCompletion  was mistyping

Comment: I would rather change `WaitAll` to `WhenAll` so you are not blocking the thread, specially for further readers on this question.

Comment: @Brat, I changed it with WhenAll

Comment: problem with this approach is that fire a compiler warning level 1 `cs4014` which I don't like 
> Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.